# Disable Tenant and logout all users Aspnetboilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working with a multi-tenancy application using aspnetboilerplate framework.

When I disable a tenant, the users still logged until they ask to logout.

How can I force logout all users? From that tenant only.

I'm using ApplicationCookie for authentication

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: You can call `_userStore.SetSecurityStamp(user, null)` for all users in that tenant.

Comment: @aaron, i'm using .net mvc 5. I tried to set security stamp to null, but it just prevent the user to login again. My problem is that I need to quit the user imediatly, as soon as the tenant becomes disabled.

Comment: By default, you need to wait 30 minutes. Otherwise, configure `services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` in your `Startup` class' `ConfigureServices` method.